# Add vertical offset to stacked column plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, offset, column-chart

I have several stacked column charts representing drilling profiles. I want to **offset the y-position of each Borehole** to represent the actual height on the ground.

**My Data looks like this:**

```
 x layer.thickness layer.depth Petrography    BSCategory  Offset
 0             0.2         0.2        silt     Drilling1      0
 0             1.0         1.2      gravel     Drilling1      0
 0             3.0         4.2        silt     Drilling1      0
 4             0.4         0.4        silt     Drilling2     -1
 4             0.8         1.2      gravel     Drilling2     -1
 4             2.0         3.2        sand     Drilling2     -1
```

**My minimum working code so far is this:**

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,0,4,4,4), layer.thickness = c(0.2,1.0,3.0,0.4,0.8,2.0), 
                 layer.depth = c(0.2,1.2,4.2,0.4,1.2,3.2), 
                 Petrography = c("silt", "gravel", "silt", "silt", "gravel", "sand"),
                 BSCategory = c("Drilling1","Drilling1","Drilling1","Drilling2","Drilling2","Drilling2"),
                 Offset = c(0,0,0,-1,-1,-1))

# provide a numeric ID that stops grouping individual petrography items
df <- transform(df,ix=as.numeric(factor(df$BSCategory)));


drilling <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = layer.thickness, group = ix, fill = Petrography)) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_line(),
        aspect.ratio=1) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE), width= .15,color="black") +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), name ="Depth [m]") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", breaks = df$x, labels=paste(df$BSCategory,"\n",df$x,"m"), name="") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gravel"='#f3e03a', "sand"= '#e09637', "silt"='#aba77d'))

print(drilling)
```

**This is my output so far (with red indicating what it should look like):**

[image: Example of drilling profiles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to work with `geom_rect` here (bar charts are/should be anchored at zero). First we need to calculate `y` start and end positions for each sample:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[ , `:=`(start = start <- c(Offset[1] + c(0, cumsum(head(layer.thickness, -1)))),
                  end = start + layer.thickness), by = BSCategory]
```

`geom_rect` has both `fill` and `color` aesthetics, which makes it easy to add a border to each individual sample.

```
w <- 0.5 # adjust to desired width

ggplot(data = df, aes(xmin = x - w / 2, xmax = x + w / 2, ymin = start, ymax = end,
                      fill = Petrography, group = Petrography)) +
  geom_rect(color = "black") +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), name ="Depth [m]") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", breaks = df$x, labels = paste(df$BSCategory,"\n", df$x, "m"), name = "") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gravel" = '#f3e03a', "sand" = '#e09637', "silt" = '#aba77d')) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

---

Alternatively, `geom_segment` could be used. `geom_segment` doesn't have a `fill` `aes`, so we need to change to `color`:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, xend = x, y = start, yend = end, color = Petrography, group = ix)) +
  geom_segment(size = 5) +
  scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0, 0), name ="Depth [m]") +
  scale_x_continuous(position = "top", breaks = df$x, labels = paste(df$BSCategory,"\n", df$x, "m"), name = "") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gravel" = '#f3e03a', "sand" = '#e09637', "silt" = '#aba77d')) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

To add borders, see [Add border to segments in geom_segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999894/add-border-to-segments-in-geom-segment).

Comment: perfect thank you very much again! Just for everyone else: I added two additional `geom_segments` more to create the black border look as the image in my question indicates: 
`geom_segment(aes(x=(x), xend=(x), y=start-0.014, yend=end+0.014), size=drill_width+1, color="black") +
  geom_segment(size = drill_width) +
  geom_segment(size = drill_width, color = "black", aes(y=start-0.014, yend=start, x = x, xend = x)) + ...`